# SyncHttpClient and AsyncHttpClient

Tags: android, loopj, asynchttpclient

I would like to know why I can successfully upload a file to a server using `AsyncHttpClient` but not when using `SyncHttpClient`.

The following setting yields successful result:

1. `MultipartEntityBuilder` to build my multipart upload request + `AsyncHttpClient` to post it. Posting the request is triggered by tapping a button in the activity.

However, because I want to upload in an `IntentService`, I use `SyncHttpClient`, and the following setting does not successfully upload the file.

2. `MultipartEntityBuilder` + `SyncHttpClient` + `IntentService`.

Below is how I build and send my request, which is the same in settings 1 and 2. The `upload` method is placed inside a helper class. And is invoked on a singleton instance, which when constructed its `mContext` is also set. `client` is a static instance variable of the helper class; `client` is a `AsyncHttpClient` in setting 1 and a `SyncHttpClient` in setting 2.

```
// MyUploadHelper.java

public void upload(File f) {
    String fileName = file.getName();

    MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
    builder.addTextBody("api", "SYNO.FileStation.Upload");
    // some more addTextBody omitted
    builder.addBinaryBody("filename", file, ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, fileName);

    HttpEntity entity = builder.build();

    client.post(mContext, getAbsoluteUrl(),
                entity, "multipart/form-data",
                new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
                        // This part can be reached in both settings. But in setting 2, the server returns "Unknown error of file operation".
                    }
                });
}
```

The method is called this way:

```
MyUploadHelper.getInstance(this).upload(aFile);
```

where `this` is an `Activity` in Setting 1 and an `IntentService` in Setting 2.

Finally, Happy New Year in advance!

Comment: I still cannot get that to work. But I have switched to Android's `HttpClient`, and it works in both settings.

Comment: Hey, actually you can using Synchttpclient, just use RequestParams and put the absolute path of your image as new File into the RequestParams object. I can give you a small snippet if you want. Thanks.